# 'Read-only file system' locked me out, won't boot

Tags: boot, read-only, initramfs, busybox

I'm running Linux mint kde on a macbook air. Today I logged in and tried to open Firefox, it wouldn't open. I did some troubleshooting and I found I couldn't modify files. It said it was a 'read-only' file system and that I need to "contact my administrator". I rebooted the system and it didn't boot up again. It goes to a command line saying `BusyBox built-in shell (ash)` and has `initramfs` as the user.

This is my only computer and I don't know what I'm doing, I really need it to boot up again. Please help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

file system which is booted in read only mode(ro) and user not able to create any file in / directory:--

first check current format of root file system

## mount

it will show like /dev/sda1 is mount on / as ro or rw if it is in ro mode we have to run manual fsck command but remember DO NOT RUN THIS COMMAND ON A MOUNTED FILE SYSTEM IT MAY CURRUPT DATA for that boot system in recovery mode or recue mode

## fsck /dev/sda1 -y

## reboot

## mount -o remount,rw /dev/sda1  (To mount file system in rw mode)

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the problem, I booted into recovery mode in GRUB and ran `fsck /dev/<root-partition>`. I wouldn't do this without looking at the other answers though.